# column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A\in M_{m\times n}\mathbb{(R)}$, show that $\mathcal{R}(AA^t)=\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $\mathcal{R}(A^tA)=\mathcal{R}(A^t)$ where $\mathcal{R}$ denotes the column space of matrix.

How can I prove it

$$\forall x\in \mathcal{R}(AA^t)\rightarrow x\in \mathcal{R}(A)$$
$$\forall x\in\mathcal{R}(A)\rightarrow x\in\mathcal{R}(AA^t)$$

but I'm not sure, can anyone help me?

Comment: "I'm not sure" is not "I don't know". What have you tried?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel In fact this is the idea I had, but I do not know how to prove using it.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, long time no see. you doing alright?

Comment: @abel I'm around all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one easier.  $$ x \in R(AA^\top) \to x = AA^\top y = A(A^\top y) $$ so $x \in R(A).$

for the second part, you will need the nullity theorem: $$ \dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(R(A)) = \text{number of columns of } A $$

we will first show that $\ker(AA^\top) = \ker A^\top$ the one part $\ker A^\top \subset \ker AA^\top$ is easy to see. for the reverse, suppose $x \in \ker AA^\top.$  then $|A^\top x|^2 = (A\top x)^\top A^\top x = x^\top AA^\top x = 0$ that implies $A^\top x = 0, x \in \ker(A^\top)$

nullity theorem implies that $ \dim R(A) = \dim R(AA^\top) $ together with $R(AA^\top) \subset R(A)$ gives that $$R(A) = R(AA^\top) $$